# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que la última fila de la tabla se vea distinta?

Tags: foreach, bootstrap

Tengo un dilema, necesito ver si se puede hacer que la ultima fila de una tabla que tiene como resultados de un foreach sea diferente. por ejemplo:

[image: Tabla de aportes y salidas]

Como se pueden dar cuenta en la imagen adjunta, la ultima y penúltima fila tienen el mismo resultado, los datos los voy a traer un un stored procedure, en el metí el resultado total, pero antes los tenía separados, ahora lo que quiero hacer es hacer un solo query (en este caso ejecución de un SP) y me traiga los resultados y el total, ya que sino se puede, para mayor facilidad solo quito el total del SP y hago siempre los 2 querys

Answer (score 0):

Podes darle estilos en css con el selector :last-of-type

Comment: Puedo hacerlo con bootstrap?

Comment: Una buena respuesta muestra cómo, explica el por qué y educa al usuario. Sería útil que ampliaras tu explicación.

Comment: Gracias @Gab me ayudo, buscaré si hay algo similar en bootstrap, sino pues ya con esto.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo he logrado aplicando indicaciones en el CSS, basicamente dependiendo de las columas de tu tabla asitnas el valor, intenta agregar a tu CSS, donde tienes estilos de tu tabla lo siguiente:

```
tbody>:nth-child(6){
color:red; 
 font-weight: bold;
}
```